# mysql server crashes when trying to connect to "127.0.0.1" but not to "localhost"

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, php

As the title says, when I try to connect to "localhost" everything just works:

```
mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
```

However, when I try to connect to 127.0.0.1, the server crashes without any error message. I only get this from php:

```
mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password');
PHP Warning:  Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 93. Packet size=4278363 in /media/bridge/projects/test.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in /media/bridge/projects/test.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=21551 in /media/bridge/projects/test.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in /media/bridge/projects/test.php on line 3
```

I have no idea what's going on. I've already disabled the apparmor profile, enabled query logging (but since it just happens on connect, that helps nothing), ...

I've also completely removed mysql and all the databases, but still nothing.

Any idea what's going wrong?

I'm using php7 on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: is something else listening on the mysql default port? when you specify "localhost" the connection is made with unix sockets, not via tcp ports.

Comment: Point of clarification: when you try connecting to `127.0.0.1` does the MySQL **server__ actually crash (which is what the heading implies) or is it just that the connection attempt fails? To put this in concrete terms, does the running `mysqld` process die?

Comment: When connecting to 127.0.0.1, either you are not actually connecting to port 3306 (the default port) and you're connecting to a different port, or MySQL is not listening on 3306 but something else is.  There's no indication here of the server crashing, but the client is connecting to something it doesn't expect.

Comment: Could it be that `localhost` resolves to the ipv6 address `::1` ?